# localStorage issue on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, persistence, local-storage

In page A of my website I setup a var in localStorage, and I can't retrieve it from page B! Pages A and B are in same domain and same subfolder within wwwroot.

btr is an array with {7,8,9} for instance.
Here is code from page A:

```
var btr= JSON.stringify(btr);
localStorage.setItem("btr", btr);
```

Later, before changing location to page B, I try this code:

```
var btr = localStorage.getItem("btr");
var storedbtr = JSON.parse(btr);
alert(storedbtr[0]);            // This works fine and shows value "7".
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/pageB.html";
```

Now in page B I have the same code as just above to read the btr value, and I get a btr "null" error.

I have read that localStorage is available throughout the entire domain???

Comment: What does `console.log(location.href)` show from page A and from page B? The domain and port numbers must be *exactly* the same.

Comment: _“an array with {7,8,9}”_ — just pointing out that this is an object, not an array.

Comment: Try redirecting to page B using relative URL instead like `window.location.href='/pageB.html';` is it possible that you're going from https to http ?

Comment: `var btr = JSON.stringify(btr);` - doesn't look right.

Comment: @chabz: Thanks, this working... Make it an answer and I'll vote for it.